# Which seafood (excluding seaplants) contain no small bones and are high in Omega-3s?

Tags: fish, seafood, shellfish

I really, really hate fish with a lot of small bones - I know it's edible, but it's just disgusting to me, and the feeling of it getting stuck on my gums or throat... UGHHH (sprats, anyone? Haha)

However I want to get my Omega-3s (from eating fish, not another source, for medical reasons). I am also very low on the budget, so I would *strongly* prefer something that doesn't cost as much as for example salmon (which is available without any bones). I would be baking the fish or making some kind of fish soup (not frying it), and therefore I am only interested in raw or frozen fish (not canned, stored in oil or pickled).

Also, it doesn't have to be fish, but it also cannot be seaplants. And again, I prefer something on the cheaper side (so no crabs or anything). :-)

If it matters, I live in Europe, so most things would be imported (besides, lake fish often are really high in Mercury).

Comment: Goodness! There was some confusion in the comments about small bones vs no bones and so on. I've tried to edit to clarify, but if something is still unclear, please *ask* the OP what they mean, or edit further.

Comment: Jack, this also feels potentially a bit broad because really *any* large fish is going to avoid the tiny bones like sprat, and generally either be a boneless/deboned cut, or at worst have larger bones. Is there some reason that just buying whatever's available in your area won't work out? I guess you only want the absolute highest Omega 3 content, not just a decent amount like all fish have?

Comment: @Cascabel Sorry for a late reply - I had some computer trouble... Well, the reason is that the fish here are lake fish, and lake fish either have low levels of Omega-3 or contain high levels of mercury. My main reason, however, is Omega-3 as you suggested - lake fish simply do not have much of it...

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking large fish are often sold without bones and they are lare enough to be easy to avoid.

If you dislike fish maybe you could try fresh tuna steak. It is the closest in appearance and probably in consistency and taste too you will find easily. If served rare it really looks like rare beef.

It is often found clean and boneless in markets (depending on our region), and if any bones are present they will likely be big and easy to avoid. Probably not the cheapest of fish, but it is often server frozen in pre-packaged portions which are probably cheaper than the fresh alternative.

[image]

One other option is [Blue Shark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_shark#Relationship_to_humans) (Tintureira). I have only recently found out about it myself. Where I live (Portugal) it is only found in the frozen fish section of certain surpermarkets, but it is relatively cheap as far as fish goes (not very thought after), and sold in small portions too for individual servings.

It also has a firm consistency closer to meat, and very similar to swordfish which is very thought after and tends to be very expensive.

As far as bones go being a shark it is from the [Cartilaginous fish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chondrichthyes) family like all sharks, rays etc, so bones are actually flexible, and some times even edible if you enjoy the texture.

[image]

[image]

If you are just trying to avoid fish bones you could also try squid or cuttlefish wish have a firm rubbery texture, and no bones in the traditional sense. They do have some hard central parts that should be easily cleaned before cooking.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the fish you mentioned are one of the highest on the planet in mercury. I do love fish taste though, I am just trying to avoid bones because I find them unedible... Well, I have not seen cattlefish in the shops here, but I have seen squid - I tried it once and loved it. Unfortunately it costs a fair bit and has very little of Omega-3.